# Insert values into datetime column from other datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I am facing an issue with a query that is supposed to insert rows into a table.

The table has the following attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[New_Table](
    [ID] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Position] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [...]
    [OrderDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [...]
 CONSTRAINT [PK_New_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [Position] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The `OrderDate` column is the only datetime column in the table.

The `OrderDate` is retrieved from the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Old_Table](
    [ID] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Number] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [...]
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [...]
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Old_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_A_Kopf] ASC,
    [Number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The query is a simple one:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[New_Table]
SELECT DISTINCT
  DataTable.ID,
  DataTable.Position,
  DataTable.System,
  b.Date
FROM
  DataTable LEFT JOIN
  (   SELECT
        OldTable.ID,
        OldTable.Date
      FROM
        OldTable
      WHERE
        OldTable.Number = <Condition>) b ON DataTable.ID = b.ID
```

The join with `DataTable` has no other datetime columns.

When I try to run the query, I receive the following error message:

```
Meldung 241, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 2
Fehler beim Konvertieren einer Zeichenfolge in ein Datum und/oder eine Uhrzeit.
```

Which translates to `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`.

I've tried to put it around a case when function with IsDate but it didn't work either. NULL values are allowed as seen in the table Definition for `New_Table`.

All of this is being run in:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                     2.6 3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.10.9200.17054
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.34209
Betriebssystem                      6.1.7601
```

Comment: Test your code `SELECT DISTINCT ...` before you insert: Format of column b.date?

Comment: we are not hear to fix your bug. Try to insert with column name specified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you put your Date/Time column into wrong place in your destination table.

Comment: This was actually the solution to the Problem.